# Can't share variables between pthreads, values are different

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I'm trying to program a web server, using a thread pool, where the main thread takes a connection, passes it to a thread, and the thread processes it.

I have a struct for each thread, and a workQueue to hold them

```
struct worker {
    pthread_t* thread;
    struct queue* workerQueue;
    char* busy;
    int connfd;
    int id;
};

struct queue {
    int start;
    int end;
    int size;
    struct worker* workers;
};
```

The main thread sets up the queue and threads, and loops over connections

```
  struct queue* workerQueue;
            workerQueue = (struct queue*) constructQueue(10);
            int j;
            int* testParam;
            //create workers and put in queue
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                struct worker* w = &(workerQueue->workers[j]);
                w = (struct worker*)constructWorker(processConnection,testParam, workerQueue,j);
                queueAdd(workerQueue,w);
            }
connection = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
        puts("got connection\n");


         w =(struct worker*) queueRemove(workerQueue);
        //w->connfd = connection;
        w->busy = "BUSY";
        printf("Worker %d has accepted a connection and is %s\n",w->id,w->busy);
```

using these two functions..

```
   struct queue* constructQueue(int numThreads)
    {
        struct queue* q = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
        q->start = 0;
        q->end = 0;
        q->workers = (struct worker* )malloc(sizeof(struct worker)*numThreads);
        q->size = numThreads;
        return q;
    }

struct worker* constructWorker(void* (*function)(void*),void* param, struct queue* wq, int i)
{
    struct worker* w = (struct worker*)malloc(sizeof(struct worker));
    w->workerQueue = wq;
    char * busy = (char*)malloc(10);
    w->busy= "IDLE";
    w->connfd = 0;
    w->id = i;
    pthread_t t;
    w->thread = &t; 
    pthread_create(w->thread,NULL,function,w);
    return w;
}
```

...and the function the threads use is

```
void* processConnection(void* serverThread)
{
        //cast serverthread
        struct worker* w;
        char* b;
        int threadID;
        w = (struct worker*)serverThread;
        b = w->busy;
        threadID = w->id;


        while (1)
        {
            char c[10];
            printf("\nbusy: %s, thread: %d\n",b,threadID);
            gets(c)
```

;

What I would like to happen is: the workers get created, with busy set to IDLE, and begin busy waiting. then in the main loop, a connection is accepted and assigned to a worker, and the workers busy value is set to BUSY. then in processConnections, if a thread is busy, it should actually process it. The problem is, although my queue contains pointers not value, when I update the workers in the main thread, it doesnt seem to affect the value of the workers in processConnection. I can set busy to BUSY and have it print that out in the main loop, but the value of busy is always IDLE in processConnection. Any ideas?

Comment: If accessing a variable concurrently, access to it shall be serialised by using a mutex. For *pthreads* this can be done using a variable of type `pthread_mutex_t`. Please read `man pthread_mutex_init`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't seeing the updated value in the other thread because there is no synchronization point between the threads. Compiler optimizations and cache (in)consistency are two reasons why this happens. To keep the same strategy you need a memory barrier. If you are using gcc, the easiest way is to put `__sync_synchronize()` before reading the shared data and after writing the shared data.

Another thing you need to fix is when you do

```
pthread_t t;
w->thread = &t;
```

The memory of `t` is liable to be reused after that function returns. You cannot take the address of a local variable and store it in a way that will outlive the lifetime of the function. The proper thing to do is have a `pthread_t` field in `struct worker` and pass the address of the field to `pthread_create`:

```
pthread_create(&w->thread, ...);
```

Comment: fixed the pthread create issue, cheers. Unfortunately syncchronise() did nothing. I also tried throwing in some mutexs, but they just seem to create a deadlock

Answer (score 1):

Try changing definition of `busy` to

```
volatile char * busy;
```

This tells the compiler that the value of this variable can change while the code is running, even if the code isn't accessing that variable explicitly.

However, you have many other problems. For example,

```
char * busy = (char*)malloc(10);
w->busy= "IDLE";
```

will leak memory that has been allocated by `malloc`.
Don't try to use strings for keeping track of state. Define an `enum {IDLE, BUSY}` instead and define `busy` to be a variable of that type.

Comment: Nothing :( thanks anyway though. I'm aware of the memory leak, but its secondary to getting the damn thing working...

Comment: `volatile` is not meant to be used to serialise access to variables which are being used concurrently between different threads. Use a mutex for this.

Comment: Not only does it leak, but the malloc doesn't do anything.  busy and w->busy are two totally different locations, and even if they were, "IDLE" is a static string that is being assigned to.   The malloc'ed storage isn't being written to at all.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest adding 2 mutexes one at  worker and one at queue

```
   struct worker {
      pthread_t* thread;
      struct queue* workerQueue;
      mutex_t QueueMutex;
      char* busy;
      int connfd;
      int id;
      };`

   struct queue {
       int start;
       int end;
       int size;
       mutex_t workermutex;
       struct worker* workers;
   };
```

Your code should work like below

When you creating a new socket, have a lock on the workermutex and then assign an connection

The worker threads each time locks the QueueMutex and adds/deletes data from the queue for processing .